# SSL on internal linux devices

Tags: linux, ssl, https, openssl

I am trying to get HTTPS/SSL to work with linux devices running on an internal network at customers.

I am developing a website that needs to communicate with a linux device running as our customers to give access to physical devices like printer and scanners. This worked fine until Chrome updated their security which means that we cannot use the application cache anymore unless we are running HTTPS. This forces us to communicate with the linux device via HTTPS also, but we only have self signed certificates for the devices and these are rejected in the browser.

I have been trying to figure out a way of getting this to work without having to manually install certificates on the customer devices. One of the ideas of our product is that it can be used on all devices without installation.

So far I have had no luck in figuring out a way to get around the security in the browser, or setting up certificates in a way where the browser doesn't reject them.

Our website is running Angular and I have tried using the Request package where it should be possible to disable rejection of invalid SSL certificates but no luck.

I have considered using websockets but as the initial handshake will be done using a HTTPS request I expect this won't work either as the handshake cannot be done without the browser failing over the certificate.

I have also been in contact with GlobalSign that just confirmed everything I have read so far, that this can only be solved by installing a chain of trust on the devices that need to access the linux devices over the internal network.

So what I am looking for is any alternative way of communicating with the linux device that will work while the website is running HTTPS. Or some way of getting valid certificates for the linux device that won't be rejected by the browser.

Comment: Use either certificates issued by a CA present in the browser trust store, or create an internal CA and update browser truststore to list it in which case you are then back to first case, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

How do the other devices see this website? By a pubic hostname? By private non-FQDN host? If the other devices see the website as any valid FQDN hostname, then you can issue a free LetsEncrypt SSL for that host, and use internally (once issued).

Comment: The devices doesn't see the website it is the other way around. The website calls the devices on a local IP so I do not have any DNS names to use in the certificates.